# Как реализовать вывод данных из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

***!!!РЕШЕНО***


Дано:
таблица mysql и три поля

```
+-----------+--------------+---------+
|id-значения| id-категории | Имя     |
+-----------+--------------+---------+
|           |              |         |
|  attr_1   |     1        |  name_1 |
|           |              |         |
+------------------------------------+
|           |              |         |
|  attr_2   |     2        |  name_2 |
|           |              |         |
+-----------+--------------+---------+
```

нужно выводить поле **Имя** в два разных поля, по id-категории
Но получаю я их по id-значения (`SELECT FROM LEFT JOIN ON WHERE`)
Вопрос: как выводить **Имена** из категории **1** в одну переменную, а **Имена** из категории **2** в другую, что бы получилось что-то типа:

```
echo "Это поле 1 и Именем $name_1";
echo "А это поле 2 и Именем $name_2";
```

Оригинал кода:

```
if ($res = $mysqli->query("
       SELECT
       $pt.product_id,
       $pt.`alias_ru-RU` AS product_url,
       $pt.product_ean,
       $pt.`product_quantity` AS quantity,
       $pt.product_price,
       $pt.`name_ru-RU` AS name,
       $pt.image,
       $pt.`short_description_ru-RU` AS description,
       $ct.`alias_ru-RU` AS cat_url,
       $ct.category_id,
       <b>$attr.`name_ru-RU` AS size,
       $attr.`name_ru-RU` AS color,</b>
       FROM $pt
       LEFT JOIN $pc ON $pt.product_id = $pc.product_id
       LEFT JOIN $ct ON $pc.`category_id` = $ct.category_id
       LEFT JOIN $pa ON $pt.product_id = $pa.product_id
       <b>LEFT JOIN $attr ON $pa.attr_2 = $attr.value_id
       LEFT JOIN $attr ON $pa.attr_1 = $attr.value_id</b>
       WHERE
       parent_id = 0
       ORDER BY product_id"))

    while( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() ) {

        if($row['quantity']>0) { $available = 'true'; }
        else { $available = 'false'; }
        ...
        echo $row['size'];
        echo $row['color'];
        ...
```

**UPD#1**
добавил алиасы, что не так сделал??

```
if ($res = $mysqli->query("
       SELECT
       ...
       $attr2.`name_ru-RU` AS size,
       $attr1.`name_ru-RU` AS color
       FROM $pt
       ...
       LEFT JOIN $attr $attr2 ON $pa.attr_2 = $attr2.value_id
       LEFT JOIN $attr $attr1 ON $pa.attr_1 = $attr1.value_id

       WHERE
       ...

       echo $row['size'];
       echo $row['color'];
```

...не работает...


**UPD#2**
**РЕШЕНО**

```
SELECT
       ...
       A2.name_ru-RU AS size,
       A1.name_ru-RU AS color
       ...
       FROM $pt
       ...
       LEFT JOIN $attr AS A2 ON $pa.attr_2 = A2.value_id
       LEFT JOIN $attr AS A1 ON $pa.attr_1 = A1.value_id
       ...
```

`echo $row['size'];
   echo $row['color'];`

Решение найдено, отображается все корректно.

Хотелось бы услышать мнение - допустимо ли такое использование или есть какие-то недочеты.

Comment: если поможет, то это Joomla! 3.5.1 и Joomshopping 4.14.1

Comment: А вы талицам алиасы дайте и сразу поймете из какой что брать `left join $attr as A1 ON ... left join $attr as A2 ON ...` и после этого спокойно обращаетесь в списке выборки к полям `A1.column` и `A2.column`

Comment: напишите детальней, что вы хотите в результате получить: вывести названия полей и их значения, или разделить продукты одной категории от другой....

Comment: хочу вывести информацию о каждом товаре (из Joomshopping) в файл, при этом нужно вывести атрибуты №1 и №2 в разные строчки. Они есть у каждого товара, но в разных сочетаниях. Так вот нужно выводит два поля: Цвет и Размер, а пока получается только один из этих атрибутов вывести без ошибок. для одного атрибута срабатывает если добавить: _$attr.`name_ru-RU` AS size,_ и _LEFT JOIN $attr ON $pa.attr_2 = $attr.value_id_

Comment: с алиасами вроде все логично, кажется даже правильно, но не могу понять как реализовать...

Comment: добавил код с использованием алиасов (не работает), что не так???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

правильное использование алиасов, рабочий вариант:

```
SELECT
       ...
       A2.name_ru-RU AS size,
       A1.name_ru-RU AS color
       ...
       FROM $pt
       ...
       LEFT JOIN $attr AS A2 ON $pa.attr_2 = A2.value_id
       LEFT JOIN $attr AS A1 ON $pa.attr_1 = A1.value_id
       ...


   echo $row['size'];
   echo $row['color'];
```